# Cannot use pip to install anything in Python 2.7.5, on Mac OSX

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, package-managers

This is starting to get really frustrating. I simply want to use pip to install packages for Python, however NOTHING I do seems to work, and NOTHING recognizes pip!

- I am on Mac OSX, 10.9.5.
- I installed Python 2.7.5 via brew.
- I went through [this website](http://dubroy.com/blog/so-you-want-to-install-a-python-package/) and installed virtualenv.

Now. I want to use pip to start to install packages for Python. *How exactly do I do that?* In the command line when I type:

> $ pip install numpy

I get:

> -bash: pip: command not found

What is going on? Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed pip?

Comment: You probably need to install `pip`. It doesn't come with Python until Python 3.4.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Can I install pip via brew?

Comment: download get-pip.py from here https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Comment: Mac OSX comes pre-installed with Python 2.7.x so no need to install it via homebrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pip` has not yet been installed. You can either [download and install pip directly](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html) as per their documentation or run:

```
easy_install pip
```

... in your Terminal. If that doesn't work, you may need to run it as a superuser. In that case, try `sudo easy_install pip`. As of Python 3.4, `pip` is included.

Comment: Ah! The sudo worked. Ok so how, the auto-complete shows many 'pips'. I have `pip`, `pip2`, and `pip2.7` - which do I use?...

Comment: I'd use the base `pip` unless you have a special need and/or you're also using python 3 and you need to specify which one you'd like to use.

Comment: OK. I guess I am wondering why there is a `pip2.7`, and if this is the one I should be using for my installation of packages, since my Python is in fact 2.7.5?... Thanks.

Comment: My understanding of `pip` is that it will use the newest / highest version of pip available. I believe `pip2.7` corresponds to Python 2.7.* and is available in case you _need_ to specify the version of Python (py2.7 vs 3.4 for example). In this case, I think `pip` is fine.

Comment: Thanks! This has helped a lot.

Comment: Wow @KevinLondon, way to copy my answer.

Comment: @WMios: we were composing our answers at the same time. I upvoted yours as well, I don't see it as a competition.

Comment: @KevinLondon, sorry, didn't realize you had written it at the same time. I up voted your's as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install pip:

```
easy_install pip
```